# How to get all sub-elements of an element tree with Python ElementTree?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I want to find a way to get all the sub-elements of an element tree like the way `ElementTree.getchildren()` does, since `getchildren()` is deprecated since Python version 2.7.
I don't want to use it anymore, though I can still use it currently.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

All sub-elements (descendants) of `elem`:

```
all_descendants = list(elem.iter())
```

A more complete example:

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> a = ET.Element('a')
>>> b = ET.SubElement(a, 'b')
>>> c = ET.SubElement(a, 'c')
>>> d = ET.SubElement(a, 'd')
>>> e = ET.SubElement(b, 'e')
>>> f = ET.SubElement(d, 'f')
>>> g = ET.SubElement(d, 'g')
>>> [elem.tag for elem in a.iter()]
['a', 'b', 'e', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g']
```

To exclude the root itself:

```
>>> [elem.tag for elem in a.iter() if elem is not a]
['b', 'e', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g']
```

Comment: Sorry Eli, but maybe I didn't make myself understood, I just want to get all the sub-elements, not also the root. i.e. the root is unwanted here. but I think your method also contains the root object, right?

Comment: But what if there are more than one sturct with tag 'a' nested in element 'a' and I want to get all sub-elements of all 'a' structs?

Comment: The element objects are iterable also without using the `iter()`.  The element behaves also like a list; so, you can also index the subelements.

Comment: @pepr: yes, but that only gives you the element's immediate children, not all descendants

Comment: @Eli Bendersky: I see.  But the `getchildren()` also returns only the immediate children.  The old equivalent of the new `list(elem.iter())` is the `list(elem.getiterator())`.  It depends what Steven really wants.

Answer (score 19):

in the pydoc it is mentioned to use list() method over the node to get child elements.
`list(elem)`

Comment: You can also do things like `for child in elem` and `last_child = elem[-1]`.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to get all elements 'a', you can use:

```
a_lst = list(elem.iter('a'))
```

If the `elem` is also 'a', it will be included.

Answer (score 3):

None of the existing answers will find all children. This solution uses BeautifulSoup instead of ETree, but will find all children, instead of just top-level:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    

with open(filename) as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f, 'xml')

results = soup.find_all('element_name')
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this does not correspond to OP actual question but in a greater sense I would suggest that if someone want to get all elements named with a certain name e.g. 'object' can use (an alternative approach to [@Turtles Are Cute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42552523/4298200) which to me at least seems more natural):

```
objs = tree.findall('object')
```

which also returns a list.