# lxml - get a flat list of elements

Tags: python, dom, tree, lxml, flatten

I'd like to flatten an lxml etree (specifically, HTML, if it matters.)  How would I go about getting a flat list of all elements in the tree?

Comment: http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#tree-iteration

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get all sub-elements of an element tree with Python ElementTree?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10408927/how-to-get-all-sub-elements-of-an-element-tree-with-python-elementtree)

Comment: quit voting to close.  i need complete, recursive listing of all elements.  i.e. tree.flatten().

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the [`.iter()`](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#tree-iteration) method, like so:

```
from lxml import etree

xml = etree.XML('''<html><body>
                   <p>hi there</p><p>2nd paragraph</p>
                   </body></html>''')

# If you want to visit all of the descendants
for element in xml.iter():
    print element.tag

# Or, if you want to have a list of all the descendents
all_elements = list(xml.iter())
print [element.tag for element in all_elements]
```

Comment: accepting for list comprehension:  elements = [ element for element in tree.iter()].  actually, more elegant, is list(tree.iter()) .