# "None" result at Parsing XML with ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, elementtree

I've tried everything to get a XML content but all I've got is a 'None' as return. Could anybody help me?

The code I'm trying is:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

parsedXML = ET.parse("C:\\Users\\denis\\Documents\\Projetos\\NFe\\Arquivos\\33180601279711000100550020001554261733208443-nfeo.xml")


for node in parsedXML.getroot():
    email = node.find('cNF')
    phone = node.find('natOp')
    street = node.find('nNF')


print(email)
```

Part of the XML (content is bigger than this) is right bellow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<nfeProc xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" versao="3.10">
<NFe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
<infNFe versao="3.10" Id="NFe33180601279711000100550020001554261733208443">
<ide>
<cUF>33</cUF>
<cNF>73320844</cNF>
<natOp>VENDA DE PRODUCAO DO ESTABELECIMENTO</natOp>
<indPag>1</indPag>
<mod>55</mod>
<serie>2</serie>
<nNF>155426</nNF>
<dhEmi>2018-06-25T16:06:33-03:00</dhEmi>
<dhSaiEnt>2018-06-25T16:06:08-03:00</dhSaiEnt>
<tpNF>1</tpNF>
<idDest>2</idDest>
<cMunFG>3304557</cMunFG>
<tpImp>2</tpImp>
<tpEmis>1</tpEmis>
<cDV>3</cDV>
<tpAmb>1</tpAmb>
<finNFe>1</finNFe>
<indFinal>1</indFinal>
<indPres>9</indPres>
<procEmi>0</procEmi>
<verProc>NeoGrid NFe 1.63.4</verProc>
</ide>
<emit>
```

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

You are using an XML document with namespaces, so you need to provide it during you call, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14853417/5962321).

Here, we get

```
namespaces = {'n': 'http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe'}
root = parsedXML.getroot()
root.find('n:NFe', namespaces)
```

to return the element, while `root.find('NFe')` returns `None`.

Also note that `find` and `findall` only search the direct children, not nested children (cf. [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#finding-interesting-elements)), which mean that you will have to iter over children (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10409082/5962321) for an example).