# Finding Tags within an XML file with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, xml-parsing

I need some help in my python code for handling an XML file. I want to get subtags and store them in lists and do some stuff with them. Until now my code was working because I was thinking that the XML structure is the same for every file i had. so I used ElementTree library for parsing etc, then .findall(tagname) and after that I did some stuff with the lists. But then I realized that some files have more tags and because of that I don't get everything i need. To give you an idea,

```
<parent tag (same for every file)>
  <tag1>
    .....
  </tag1>
  <tag2>
    .....
  </tag2>
  <tag3>
    .....
  </tag3>
  <unknown tag1>
    .....
  </unknown tag1>
  <unknown tag2>
    .....
  </unknown tag2>
  <tag2>
    .....
  </tag2>
  <tag2>
    .....
  </tag2>
  <unknown tag1>
    .....
  </unknown tag1>
</parent tag>
```

So my current code is:

```
list1 = root.findall('tag1')
list2 = root.findall('tag2')
list3 = root.findall('tag3')
```

and then I do something for what is inside those tags which is working. I need help on how to detect every tag under parent tag, and then store them in a list so i can do the findall() funtion for each tag in the list. Something like

```
List_of_tags = [tag1, tag2, tag3, unknown tag1, etc]

for tag in list_of_tags:

....
```

Thank you in advance!

I actually parse xml files with ElemntTree like that:

```
try:
    tree = ET.parse(filename)
except IOError as e:
    print 'No such file or directory'
else:
    root = tree.getroot()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [xmltodict](https://pypi.org/project/xmltodict/)

```
pip install xmltodict
```

And here's how you can get all the child tags under a parent tag

```
import xmltodict
my_xml = """<parent_tag>
  <tag1>
    .....
  </tag1>
  <tag2>
    .....
  </tag2>
  <tag3>
    .....
  </tag3>
  <unknown_tag1>
    .....
  </unknown_tag1>
  <unknown_tag2>
    .....
  </unknown_tag2>
  <tag2>
    .....
  </tag2>
  <tag2>
    .....
  </tag2>
  <unknown_tag1>
    .....
  </unknown_tag1>
</parent_tag>"""

xmld = xmltodict.parse(my_xml)

child_tags = xmld['parent_tag'].keys()

for child_tag in child_tags:
    print(child_tag)
```

The output will look like this:

```
tag1
tag2
tag3
unknown_tag1
unknown_tag2
```

Comment: first of all, thank you for your time. I actually parse the xml file with element tree, and  then i get the root. I used your code and instead of my_xml i was thinking of using root. But i get an error "must be string or read-only buffer, not Element". I tried fromstring() method but i get the same error. Can you help?

Comment: Can you please update your question to include how you are parsing the xml file

Comment: I just did it, sorry for that

Comment: See if this helps you to convert the element tree to string https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15304229/convert-python-elementtree-to-string/15304351#15304351

Comment: If you want to use element tree instead of xmltodict to do this, you may find this helpful as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10408927/how-to-get-all-sub-elements-of-an-element-tree-with-python-elementtree/10409082#10409082

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped me a lot. I will update the post later, to help others too. Feel free to leave feedback after that!!! Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

----- SOLUTION -----

```
child_tags = root.getchildren()
for child in child_tags:
    k = child.tag
    tags.append(k)

for tag in tags:
    list1 = root.findall(tag)
    tagslist = tagslist + list1

#remove duplicates
tagslist = list(dict.fromkeys(tagslist))
```